# Rounded Corners Optimization

Tags: html, image-processing, css

Now that CSS3 includes styles to add rounded corners to images automatically, does this mean that adding rounded corners to images without CSS should be discarded?

I would assume that shaving off some of the image would load the page faster then shaving off some of the CSS, but at the same time, that would all depend on how fast the browser renders the rounded corners from CSS. Also, images with rounded corners should be completely browser independent and I could assume they would look, and act the same in all browsers.

If you are capable of creating your own images with rounded corners, is that the best way to go? Or should you cut the image down to be square, and add the rounded corners using CSS?

Thanks for any help!
Metropolis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and lower [do not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413%28VS.85%29.aspx) CSS3 rounded corners. I would stick with an image-based solution for a couple more years.

**EDIT:** [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) emulates [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) on IE 6 to 8. You might want to use that for your page load time comparisons.

Comment: Looks like IE9 should support it though, although that would probably not target all browsers that it should. Like IE8/7.... http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus#target-selector